# Momentum Conserving Delta Function and Soft Gravitons

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-gravity, polarization, gauge-invariance, research-level

I am reading a paper called "Testing subleading multiple soft graviton theorem for
CHY prescription" written by Subhroneel Chakrabarti, Sitender Pratap Kashyap, Biswajit Sahoo, Ashoke Sena and Mritunjay Vermaa ([Link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.07883)). In section 2, they describe the single soft graviton theorem and more specifically, they show that, given that the two soft terms (leading and sub-leading) in the Feynman (or stripped according to the authors) amplitude factor out from the remaining non-radiative amplitude, they also factor out from the scattering (or not-stripped) amplitude. This is because of the delta function property (equation 3.7)
$$\sum_{a=1}^n\frac{\varepsilon_{(n+1),\mu\nu}p_a^{\mu}k_{(n+1),\rho}}{k_{(n+1)}\cdot p_a}p_a^{\rho}\frac{\partial}{\partial p_{a,\nu}}\delta^{(D)}(p_1+...+p_n)=0$$
where the $,$ does not stand for differenciation, but rather, it is there to distinguish spacetime indices from particle number indices. Can someone elaborate on that? Why does it hold and can this be generalized to the cased of QED?

Also, the authors say that this equation is a result of $\varepsilon_{\mu}^{\mu}=0$ and I also can not see why this is true... So, help on that point would be appreciated as well.